# How to Upgrade gem rails 4 to rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am facing issue with upgrading gem , I installed https://github.com/cle61/activeadmin-lte gem with my rails 5 application and I also fork this gem on my github account (https://github.com/yogeshwaghmare7/activeadmin-lte). but during the installation I am facing rails 4 dependency. I want to upgrade this gem.

Please provide step by step document for same.

Thanks in advance.

Yogesh Waghmare

Comment: If you want to upgrade the gem you're going to have to comb through the code and upgrade it. If you want the creator to update it, request it on git.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What error do you see? I don't fancy creating a new rails app with this dependency, just to understand the question.

Comment: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
    activeadmin-lte was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      quiet_assets was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
        rails (~> 3.1)
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    railties (= 5.1.6)

Comment: In Gemfile:
    activeadmin-lte was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      quiet_assets was resolved to 1.0.1, which depends on
        railties (~> 3.1)

    rails (~> 5.1.6) was resolved to 5.1.6, which depends on
      railties (= 5.1.6)
Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.

Comment: I don't want to upgrade gem , I want to resolve dependencies with rails 5

Comment: @YogeshWaghmare Right, so as per the error message, the issue is in [`quiet_assets`](https://github.com/evrone/quiet_assets#deprecation). That gem is deprecated. So in order to update the `activeadmin-lte`, you'll need to **remove** that dependency, and update the gem as required.

Comment: This is probably beyond the scope of a StackOverflow question. The update itself may be trivial, but you'll need to research what steps are necessary first.

Comment: StackOverflow is for specific programming questions. "Please provide step-by-step document" is not a question.

Answer (score 0):

There are many [other ActiveAdmin themes](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Themes) better maintained than LTE, which was abandoned quite some time ago. Perhaps you can try Clement's [ArcticAdmin](https://github.com/cle61/arctic_admin). Asking how to maintain your own fork of an ActiveAdmin theme is probably too broad a question for StackOverflow.